# How do I reference a variable within the Jmeter User Defined Variable control?

Tags: jmeter

I'm currently creating a test suite of API tests in JMETER.
I've created a "User Defined Variable" config element to help parameterize the tests. The value goes into the "Path" of the API request.
However.....

When I input 
  **`NAME:`**  dev.testAppUrl
   **VALUE: https://devurl/api/applications/${ID}**

the test returns an error because its treating `${ID}` as a literal string in the URL path. 
If the url is hardcoded in the test request it works fine to leave the `${ID`} in there and that value is scraped from a previous request using a "regular expression extractor control" and populated as expected, but I would love to not hardcode these path values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use eval function to get the ${ID} replaced at run time.

`${__eval(${dev.testAppUrl})}`

Comment: Do I add the eval function to the udv config element. currently lit looks like this:
Name: dev.testAppURL      Value: https://devurl/api/application/${ID}

or do I add it in the Environment Profiler>Parameterized controller which currently looks like this:
Name: testAppURL              Value: ${dev.testAppURL}

Thanks again! I'm guessing it would be one of the value elements?

Comment: whereever you want to use ${dev.testAppUrl} -> you need to use ${__eval(${dev.testAppUrl})}